# Android Virtual Device orientation (This is different)

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

AVD won't change orientation. All answers I saw says numpad 7, numpad 9, ctrl + F11, ctrl+ F12, even the link from developer.android. But my AVD only goes sideways, but not the screen orientation itself. I want to simulate the exact change orientation of a device, not just the normal avd looking sideways. Here's a pic of what I mean:

[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/w85fk4.jpg]

Even checked Auto rotate screen on android settings sideways. But still no. Lol.

Comment: does the orientation change for the home screen as well ?

Comment: what do you mean? as you can see, the whole avd flipped to the side with the screen.

Comment: i meant that same thing what @yushulx mentioned. and also are you using android:screenOrientation to lock ?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. This  is something that months ago didn't happen. It's happening with all AVDs right  now on any app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is a bug for AVD with Android 4.4. To fix the problem you may install Android 4.3 over the SDK Manager and then switch the target of your emulated device to Android 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your system settings are simply set to not rotate the screen. Go to Android settings -> Display and enable "Auto-rotate screen"

Comment: it is already checked. maybe i missed something on the creation of the avd or something?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the skin. WXGA800 worked for me