# Android rotation not working properly

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I start AVD and everything is loaded it looks like this:
[image: AVD started]

When I rotate with display (<kbd>NumPad 7</kbd>/<kbd>NumPad 9</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>/<kbd>F12</kbd>) it looks like this:
[image: AVD rotated screen]

How can I change default android rotation to portrait?

Comment: Duplicate?: [Android Virtual Device orientation (This is different)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18228049/456814)

Comment: Not sure about duplicate, because this covers also Android 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I have ADV with Android 3.0. When I try Android 4.3 everything seems to work properly so there is probably more problems not only with Android 4.4 as [Farouk Touzi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24587217/1108200) said (his solution in comments to his answer also help when you want to use Android 3.0).
Well it appears that Android versions are too wild even for ADV emulator developers...